# How do I label fluorescent fixtures converted to LED?

Tags: light-fixture, led, fluorescent

I am going to replace some regular fluorescent tubes that are about to burn out with LED ones and would like to add a sticker inside the fixture to advise a future owner to **not** install regular fluorescent tubes, but I can't seem to think of a concise verbiage for said sticker. I don't know:
"Fixture not wired for regular fluorescent use"
"Do not install regular fluorescent tubes"
Any suggestions?
**Edit:** How 'bout this: "Use with standard fluorescent tube requires rewiring; consult a licensed electrician"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't say what *shouldn't* be in there, say what *should*.  "Direct-wire LED tubes only"

I put the sticker directly behind (above) the tube so it hides the sticker.  I would place it near the lampholder which has the 120V on it, if that's a factor.

Then on the endcap of the fixture, at the power cord end, "Ballast removed. Direct wired for LED."

If the fixture doesn't have a power plug (or if it's annoyingly inaccessible), my practice is to install an internal disconnect inside the fixture [(scroll down and look for the orange connector)](http://ecmweb.com/code-basics/nec-rules-installing-lighting-circuits-greater-30v) which can be [had cheaply here](http://www.lowes.com/pd_540475-12704-30-1302S_1z0yt4q__).  It's not required for direct-wire LEDs (and several other exceptions) but it's a good thing to do, and the connectors are only a buck.

Comment: I like the "ballast removed direct wired for LED". I would point out though that a regular flourescent tube won't work anyway and no damage would result. Without a ballast the tubes would just glow on the ends possibly but would not light up. Labeling is a good idea for retrofitted fixtures though.

Comment: My mind was stuck in what not to do instead of what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I wonder if I could get a DPDT switch and wire the fixture to make it switchable?

Comment: @BillOer Sure, an SPST switch will suffice, switch the 120V hot.   I've seen pull cords used on fluorescents, have to drill a hole for that.  Since your bulbs are all 120V now, you could use a 3-way pull cord for high/low.  If your fixture has 1/2" knockouts, a motion sensor fits in one.